# Multi MOSFET IC for Controlling 12V LED strips with Arduino

Tags: arduino, mosfet, integrated-circuit

I am planing to make an arduino shield for some Home Control jobs (e.g. switching 433MHz RC Sockets, measuring temperature, check if windows are closed and controlling RGB LED lights.)

My base unit is an Arduino Mega 2560 and actually I have made the circuit on a breadboard with 6x N-channel MOSFETs (type: BUZ 71A / STP16NF06), to control my 2 RGB led Strips on via the PWM ports of the Arduino).

The problem is, that they are too big in space for the shield i am designing, so **I am looking for a IC, that combines at least 3x N-channel MOSFETS or any other way to save the space on my board.**

additional information: I am Switching 12V LED strips (3m of them and some headroom would be nice) according to the datasheet the maximum usage of the strips will be ~3A per color/channel at a supply voltage of 12V

Comment: I have rephrased the Question.

Comment: You should be more mindful in labeling community efforts as "unproductive noise" - it's simply offensive and discourages community members to help: At minimum spelling mistakes were corrected (is that noise to you?). I think the author posed a valid question, and I disagree: It is both relevant and useful (both question and answers), especially to new readers. You can revert my edit if you personally don't like it (presumably you're a mod?) - this is not the place to bash people. I attempted edit to make it more clear what is meant - it _does_ have a huge 'improve it' button there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Changed to more appropriate type of MOSFET

Rather than those huge olde style packages, how about considering a modern dual that would take up little space, such as the [AON7804](http://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AON7804.pdf)

[image]

These little guys are 26m\$\Omega\$ (max)  with 4.5V drive and are only 3mm x 3mm. Also, only 34 cents each in 25's, so all 6 will be about a dollar.

If you want to use a relatively large package such as SO-8, they're also available though not quite as high performance, but almost as low price, and should be more than okay for your application (and they're easy to solder with 50 mil pitch and no thermal pad beneath- so not as good heatsinking, but easier). The [DMG9926USD](http://www.diodes.com/datasheets/ds31757.pdf) should do nicely.

[image]

Comment: sorry, but how do I solder them? I still have some problems with small SMDs but how do I get the tin under the IC?

Comment: (in order of increasing cost) Some people have been qutie successful with toaster ovens, particularly if they augment the control (put some flux and solder paste down first). Inexpensive hot air rework tools can be used. Some very good hot air guns can be used. I have a small benchtop reflow oven I use for prototyping. Don't try using a $10 paint stripper hot air gun, you'll burn the board.

Comment: These N-mosfets have the Drains tide together, so in order to use them individually they have to be used as high side switches, and with 12v to the Drains he'll need to drive the gates with at least 16.5v. I think this will add complexity to the design.

Comment: looks as if I'll stick with my simple MOSFETS and try to order them that they are laying over each other and put some hot glue between them to prevent them from moving.

Comment: @alexan_e Oops, good catch. They're mis-categorized by Digikey's search engine. I changed to another type of MOSFET that isn't quite as low Rds(on) but still pretty good.

Comment: The Second type (SO-8 Package) is looking quite good! I am not so good in not-digital electronics (This is my first non-breadboard and ic bricking project ;-) ... will they be able to drive the LED strips with 12V when switching PWM from my Arduino (5V)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you can get by with a common Source connection (typical for an LED driver), you might be able to use the SLA5085 which is 5 MOSFET N-channel array:

[image]

with the following specs:

Vds: 60v

Id: 3A typical, max 10A

Vgs: 3v @ Id = 3A

It is available from [Digi-Key](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv606=46&FV=fff40015,fff80346&k=mosfet&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25).

Comment: In case anyone wonders about the visuals of the device (it's not shown in the datasheet), it's like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AK8sa.jpg)

Comment: @alexan_e  That looks interesting. It saves me the routing Space for common ground. But is there also one with 6 Mosfets inside? it would save an additional external one as I want to switch 2 Strops (6 Channels)

Comment: @Tobi Sorry, can't help you on that, but another option is to use two of the above devices and two discrete mosfets (which are definitely cheaper and would occupy less space that a third SLA5085). Or maybe you mean 5+1 in which case you'll need one additional mosfet.

Comment: @Tobi These devices are pretty rare, in fact Digi-Key lists a 4 MOSFET array without the common source connection but its not in stock.  Their only 6 MOSFET array is a 3-phase motor driver.  I also checked Mouser, Newark and Future Electronics without any luck.